# C# split 20 digit numbers and assign it to 5 string variables

Tags: c#

I need guide as to how I can split 20 digit numbers (e.g 77772222666611118888) and uniquely assign to five declared int variables e.g int n1,n2,n3,n4,n5.

Expected result

```
int mynumber = 77772222666611118888;
```

And, after the splitting and assigning, one gets the following:

```
n1=7777;
n2=2222;
n3=6666;
n4=1111;
n5=8888;
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure int can store that number?

Comment: Where is the number coming from? Perhaps you should be treating this as a text processing task.

Comment: There is no way this "number" would fit into a type of int. Use string to split it and then parse the results back to a type of int.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a simple regex for it

```
string mynumber = "77772222666611118888";
var ns = Regex.Matches(mynumber, @"\d{4}").Cast<Match>()
              .Select(x => x.Value)
              .ToList();
```

Comment: +1 for a simple string manipulation answer. Out of curiosity, would this work for a 19 or 21 digit number?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET if you ask whether it would throw exception, no. Output? `19=>4+4+4+4 21=>4+4+4+4+4`

Comment: I was just wondering if the regex would handle a string with length not divisible by four. From your comment, I take that it would. +1 again if I could :)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a `long` or `Decimal` to store the initial number, as its too long for an int.

Once that is done, use modulus to get the digits (in reverse), and division to get rid of the used numbers:

```
long tempNumber = number;
List<long> splitNumbers = new List<long>();

while (tempNumber > 0)
{
   long currentDigits = number % 10000;
   tempNumber = tempNumber / 10000; //Make sure this is integer division!

   //Store cuurentDigits off in your variables
   // 8888 would be the first number returned in this loop
   // then 1111 and so on
   splitNumbers.Add(currentDigits);
}

//We got the numbers backwards, so reverse the list
IEnumerable<long> finalNumberList = splitNumbers.Reverse();
```

You could also turn it into a string, and use `.Take(4)` and `int.Parse` to get your numbers.

Comment: Please, so how will the new variables get their various 4 digits now ? its not clear

Comment: @Gentlesule They are contained in `currentDigits` on each iteration of the loop as indicated in the comments. Named variables *aren't* your friend here, you'd probably need to store the numbers in an array or list. Numbered variables are a code smell anyways, so I don't feel bad having a solution that isn't compatible with them. I updated my code to be more complete.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use separate variables, you could do this:

```
        string mynumber = "77772222666611118888";
        string n1 = mynumber.Substring(0, 4);
        string n2 = mynumber.Substring(4, 4);
        string n3 = mynumber.Substring(8, 4);
        string n4 = mynumber.Substring(12, 4);
        string n5 = mynumber.Substring(16, 4);
```

If you're willing to use an array or another collection, you could do this:

```
        int stringSize = 4;
        string[] n = new string[mynumber.Length / stringSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < n.Length; i ++)
        {
            n[i] = mynumber.Substring(i*4, stringSize);
        }
```

Comment: Hmmmm.... Exactly what I'm looking for. I really appreciate the efforts of all of you

Comment: previous comment withdrawn

Answer (score 1):

You should convert myNumber to a string first,
then extract each part of this number using the substring function 
and parse those strings back to the desired integers

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined what the rules are for performing the split you asked about. Are you splitting based on position and length? Are you splitting based on runs of identical digits?

Assuming you're splitting based on runs of identical digits, you could use a *backreference* like so,

```
Regex rxSameDigits = new Regex(@"(\d)(\1)*") ;
```

The `\1` says, use the *value* of the specified group, in this case, the group starting with the first left parenthesis in the regex. So it says to

- Match any digit, followed by
- zero or more of the exact same digit

So it will match sequences like 1, 22, 333, etc. So you can simply say:

```
string   s     = "1223334444555556666667777777888888889999999990000000000" ;
string[] split = rxSameDigits.Matches(s).Cast<Match>().Select( x => x.Value ).ToArray() ;
```

And get the expected

- 1
- 22
- 333
- 4444
- 55555
- 666666
- 7777777
- 88888888
- 999999999
- 0000000000